# Change institute text color in beamer footer

Tags: beamer

How can i change text color of institute in beamer footer document?

[image]

As you can see in the image, institute text color in footer (bottom right) is like background color. I need to change it in order to make it readable. How can i do this?

My code is really simple at the moment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\usecolortheme{spruce}

\title{Progettazione e sviluppo di un'applicazione mobile per pagamenti elettronici}
\author{Antonio Falcone}
\institute{Università di Bologna}
\date{16/03/2017}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Added my code @CarLaTeX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\usecolortheme{spruce}

\setbeamercolor{institute in head/foot}{parent=palette primary}

\title{Progettazione e sviluppo di un'applicazione mobile per pagamenti elettronici}
\author{Antonio Falcone}
\institute{Università di Bologna}
\date{16/03/2017}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]