# Change text color for short title in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, fonts, color, header-footer

This question is hopefully straightforward, but I've been unable to find an answer.  How can I change the color of the "short title" in the footline of a Beamer slide?  I've tried

```
\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=blue}
```

but that (unsurprisingly) changes the title font color, not that of the short title.  [Another post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357335/change-institute-text-color-in-beamer-footer) looked promising but I don't know how to make use of it and more importantly, it doesn't appear to let one change the text in the footline to an arbitrary color.  In that vein, I'd like to be able to pick any color for the short title, but I would happily settle for someone telling me how to make it white.

MWE:

[image: Title slide with red "short title" text]

```
\documentclass[hyperref={colorlinks=true}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{fly}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}  % Remove navigation symbols

\title[Would That This Could Be Some Color Besides Red]{The Title Is White But the Short Title Is Red}
\author{}
\institute{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title in head/foot is already in white... via the `title in head/foot` template (color and font template).

But this title is also a link[1] and you use `hyperref` with the `colorlinks` option (and its default colors). So the link is written in red (the default color used by `hyperref` for links).

To keep colors defined by templates and use colored links, try the following options:

```latex
\documentclass[hyperref={colorlinks=true,allcolors=.,urlcolor=red}]{beamer}
```

To change the color used by the title in head/foot, you can change its template color:

```
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=green!40}
```

[1] Extract from *beamer user guide* (v3.62, p.72):

> By clicking on the document title in a navigation bar (not all themes show it), you will jump to the first slide of your presentation (usually the title page) except if you are already at the first slide. On the first slide, clicking on the document title will jump to the end of the presentation, if there is one. Thus by double clicking the document title in a navigation bar, you can jump to the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  That works perfectly to get the short title text color to be white.  After all my looking around yesterday, I'm still curious how to change the color arbitrarily though.  Again out of curiosity, what is the short title a link to?  The presentation itself?

Comment: @thehandoftheking Thank you for accepting my answer. You can also vote for it if you find it useful. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Terrifically useful info!